# Update Azure DevOps work item when a linked list item is updated in Sharepoint

Tags: azure-devops, sharepoint, automation, power-automate

As a newbie in power automate I still have some doubts about the correct modification of the flows. I would like to add the option to modify an existing work item to the flow below. When I modify an existing item from my sharepoint list, instead of changing the properties in the existing item, a completely new item with these changes is added to the Azure DevOps. How can I modify this flow so that duplicates are not created, but the properties of the existing work item are changed?

Maybe someone has done something like this or similar?

Any guidance, screenshots or examples on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

[Current working flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyVRP.png)

Answer (score 0):

To modify an existing work item in Azure DevOps instead of creating a new one, you need to use the "Update work item" action in Power Automate. You can add this action after the "When an item is created or modified" trigger and configure it to update the corresponding work item in Azure DevOps. To do this, you will need to map the fields in your SharePoint list to the fields in your Azure DevOps work item. You can use dynamic content to achieve this.

Here are the steps to modify the flow:

Add the "Update work item" action after the "When an item is created or modified" trigger.

In the "Update work item" action, select the Azure DevOps organization and project where the work item is located.

Select the work item type and ID that you want to update.

Map the fields in your SharePoint list to the fields in your Azure DevOps work item. You can use dynamic content to achieve this.

Save and test your modified flow.